# AndroidStudio - Activities and Layouts question

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Should I use a lot of layouts for a few activities or should I have a lot of activities with one or two layouts for each. I noticed that using a bunch of layouts for the same activity makes the activity code very messy compared to having one or two layouts for each activity, but for some reason I have the impression that having a lot of layouts instead of activities makes the app faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your use case if for example you have a recyclerview or a list in your activity, I think its generally safe to say you will have multiple layouts definitely for separation of concern. Although nowadays, I think a single activity is recommended, layouts are managed through fragments and navigation component. If you only have simple use case, I think its fair enough to reuse as much layout as possible especially if the other activity looks much like the other (Just modify the content in the class).